# How to get List of Tuple from Code Behind to Javascript

Tags: javascript, code-behind, hidden-field

I have created a list of different items say list of tuple in code behind. I want to access the same list in my javascript. I tried the same but what I am getting in result in like: `(value, value), (value, value), (value, value)...`

I want a result like **JSON** format : `[{value, value}, {value, value}...]`.

**Code Snippet I wrote is:**

```
List<Tuple<int, int>> comboPD = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                int pId = (int)dataReader["FieldName"];
                int dId = (int)dataReader["FieldName"];
                comboPD.Add(Tuple.Create(f1, f2));
            }
            hdnPDValue.Value = String.Join(",", comboPD);
```

**I accessed the same from java script through a hidden runat field. Like:**

```
var arr = [];
arr = $(".json-ProgDivIds").val();
```

Please, let me know how to get that List to javascript in mentioned format.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried string `json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(comboPD);` and then passing the variable json to your code `hdnPDValue.Value = String.Join(",", comboPD);`

Comment: Hi, @Saggy, this worked. I am getting the result in the same format what I expected but the value in Hidden-Field is considered as a single instance. Do you have any idea about it?